# rubyinstaller devkit install error rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install rubyinstaller. after

```
git clone https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller.git
```

and get in directory rubinstaller and put command

```
rake devkit sfx=1
```

I get message

```
/home/leon/rubyinstaller/sandbox/extract_utils/7za.exe" e -y 
"downloads/7z920.msi" -o"sandbox/extract_utils" "_7z.sfx" > NUL 2>&1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (126): ["/home/leon/rubyinstaller/sandbox/extract_...]
/home/leon/rubyinstaller/rake/extracttask.rb:72:in `seven_zip_get'
/home/leon/rubyinstaller/recipes/extract_utils/extract_utils.rake:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/leon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/leon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => devkit => devkit:build => devkit:msys => devkit:msys:extract => extract_utils => extract_utils:extract_utils
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

any idea ?
i am using UBUNTU 17.3

Comment: Rubyinstaller is for windows, not for linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix-like systems, such as Ubuntu or OSX, you definately should take a look at RVM or Rbenv. Personally, I prefer Rbenv with Ruby Build plugin installed.

Take a look at this link for installing Rbenv: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment

Then install Ruby Build as a Rbenv plugin: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#installing-as-an-rbenv-plugin-recommended

After that, you can easily install the versions you want: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#using-rbenv-install-with-rbenv